# How to get list of all nearby ssid's in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, homekit, wac

I want to connect my IOT device to WiFi network from my app. For that I need to fetch the WiFi connections available nearby to the iOS device and list them in my app. From that list the user will select the network and then the device gets connected to the selected network.

I've extensively searched on different portals for the same and couldn't produce some concrete reference for fetching the network list. I came across some tutorial videos on YouTube demonstrating setting up the Google Home Mini device and Amazon Echo Dot 3 device to the WiFi network. Both devices are configured with the help of their individual apps i.e Google Home App and Alexa App. In both these apps the user is presented with a list of nearby available WiFi networks. I am also providing below the links of screenshots from the tutorials videos of the network list from both those apps.

https://ibb.co/f9zf2qn // For Alexa App

https://ibb.co/B4WxvKd // For Google Home App

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1942/_index.html

Comment: Hi @JoakimDanielson I am still not getting from it. Would you please elaborate